# Talking to Angular Directive from Controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive and I want to call a method of the Directive from outside controller . That means when I click a button in the main controller , I want to hide a component in the directive . Is this really possible ,If yes please help me .

Kamal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To call directive methods outside in a controller I would share a directive control object with the controller. Inside the controller you can call methods of this control object and they get executed inside your directive.

1. create a control object inside your directive
2. share this control object with the controller using tw data binding
3. call methods on this control object inside your controller

here is a plunker that demonstrates it: http://plnkr.co/edit/MqN9yS8R5dnqTfjqldwX?p=preview

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply I need very similar to the one that you shared , but in my case I want to call the Directive method in the initialization of the controllor with out using $scope.$apply()     ..please find the below plunker and help me [http://plnkr.co/edit/a9LiBT8vlqLDdSAKKlxU?p=preview]

Comment: When the controller is run first there is no function someAction on the object myDirControl. So you need to wait till angular parses the directive and assignes the directive object to myDirControl. Is there a reason you don't want to use $apply?

Comment: Many Thanks for reply . Actually When I integrate this code in my application , I am getting  ** Error: $digest already in progress  ** . I tried using but no use , so want to find out any other alternative .Any idea using resolve : { initialize directive }  in state provider so that it will take care of initiazing the directive  before the controller gets called.

Comment: To fix the $digest error: if(!$scope.$$phase) { $scope.$apply(...) }

Comment: I tried that too , I used something like this ...            if($scope.$$phase) {
   $scope.myDirControl.someAction();
}
else {
  $scope.$apply(function() {
     $scope.myDirControl.someAction();
  });
}
In my case it always executing the If block only and ending up with an error someAction not defined on myDirControl . Can we initialize a directive in starting of the controller ?

Comment: I've updated your plunker using $scope.$apply http://plnkr.co/edit/QNl0XergHmCsYyOhNVG6?p=preview or $scope.$watch http://plnkr.co/edit/AazD549ZWB2hHO3XsoRK?p=preview

Comment: Thanks a lot bekite , I found solution for my problem . here is the plunker with my solution   -- http://plnkr.co/edit/mZ1Vd3t6uUnS4r5XdORO?p=preview?  please let me know If this solution causes any other issue ?  Thanks Kamal

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by allowing your directive to listen to a scoped property from your controller.  Using isolated scope and the `=`, you can tell your directive what to pay attention to in order to hide its component:

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.2.0-rc3-nonmin" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.3/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <button ng-click="action()">Toggle</button>
    <the-directive show-component="showIt"></the-directive>
  </body>

</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {


  $scope.showIt = true;

  $scope.action = function() {

    $scope.showIt = !$scope.showIt;
  }

  });


  myApp.directive('theDirective', function() {

    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        'showComponent': '='
      },
      template: '<div><div ng-show="showComponent">show Me!</div></div>'

    }
  })
```

Here is a [plunker demonstrating the technique](http://plnkr.co/edit/Xq6TRS?p=preview).

Comment: @bekite Thanks a lot for your reply I need very similar to the one that you shared , but in my case I want to call the Directive method in the initialization of the controllor with out using $scope.$apply()     ..please find the below plunker and help me [http://plnkr.co/edit/a9LiBT8vlqLDdSAKKlxU?p=preview]